# Disable bottom of MacBook trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, magic-trackpad, plugins

I’m interested in disabling the bottom 20% of the 2016 MacBook Pro trackpad. So a roughly 1/2” tall row across the entirety of the trackpad, on the edge furthest from the keyboard.

When sitting in a chair/couch, my hand or my stomach end up touching the bottom edge of the trackpad, because the tracking surface extends so far to the edge of the computer. This causes unwanted clicks/scrolls/other interactions. This was not the case with the previous MacBook Pro, as the trackpad was smaller and inset away from the edge of the computer.

So if I could programmatically disable some of the surface, and then put some tape over it to remind myself of where to track/click, I wouldn’t have this issue.

Is there an app or plugin that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try blue painter's tape that has a low tack so as not to leave a lot of adhesive residue on the laptop?